# Not able to display Image on IE 11 Unable to decode image at URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

After I upload the Image and update; when I try to pull it from the server it gives the below error message
**DOM7009: Unable to decode image at URL**
I have tried to search for ans online but no luck; the problem is on IE only whereas it works fine on Chrome.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the image, as well as show us how you're attempting to load it?

Comment: @Sampson I was able to solve it by unchecking the option under Compatibility view settings-->display intranet sites in compatibility view

Comment: Happy to hear you were able to resolve the issue. Given the nature of the solution, it's probably best that you close this question.

Comment: @ssam007 where do you see this compatibility view settings in visual studio? thanks :)